# Cross account S3 copy of 100Million files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-emr

I have 100 million small csv files that I have to copy from one aws account into another.

I tried to do parallel S3 copy using boto3 and also tried using aws sync. But due to the larger amount of files I could not get it done in reasonable amount time of time.

Is there any way to copy this large number of files from one account to another account S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- **Generate a list of objects** by using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects
- Pass the list to [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/batch-ops.html) and configure it to perform a **Copy** operation

See: [Cross-account bulk transfer of files using Amazon S3 Batch Operations | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/cross-account-bulk-transfer-of-files-using-amazon-s3-batch-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want to transfer files between accounts (A & B).

Attach a bucket policy to the source bucket in Account A

1 Get the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM identity (user or role) in Account B (destination account).
2 From Account A, attach a bucket policy to the source bucket that allows the IAM identity in Account B to get objects

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/Jane"},
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplesourcebucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplesourcebucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Attach an IAM policy to a user or role in Account B

1. From Account B, create an IAM customer managed policy that allows an IAM user or role to copy objects from the source bucket in Account A to the destination bucket in Account B.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplesourcebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplesourcebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexampledestinationbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexampledestinationbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Attach the customer managed policy to the IAM user or role that you want to use to copy objects between accounts.

Use the IAM user or role in Account B to perform the cross-account copy

After you set up the bucket policy and IAM policy, the IAM user or role in Account B can perform the copy from Account A to Account B. Then, Account B owns the copied objects.

To synchronize all content from a source bucket in Account A to a destination bucket in Account B, the IAM user or role in Account B can run the sync command using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI):

```
aws s3 sync s3://awsexamplesourcebucket s3://awsexampledestinationbucket
```

[AWS Refrence](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/)